# php5 mysqli object Fatal error: Call to undefined function

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm learning the basics of php5, mysqli and object programming and I would like to implement a connection as a function inside a class but I get the fatal error in the subject

```
function connexObjet(){
    include_once("conf.php");
    $f_conn = new mysqli(MYHOST, MYUSER, MYPASS, MYDB);

    // check connection
    if (!$f_conn){
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n");
        exit();
    }
    return $f_conn;
}

// début affichage de tout les articles
function showAllArticles($champs=null){

    if($champs==null){$champs = "*";}

    // connection à la bdd
    $conn = connexObjet();

    // requête sql avec variable de classe déclarée comme private
    $sql = "SELECT $champs FROM $this->table";
    $req = $conn->query($sql);

    // envoyer la requête dans un tableau associatif
    while ($data = $req->fetch_assoc()){
        $tableau[] = $data;
    }
    return $tableau;
}
```

$conn = connexObjet() returns a fatal error. Any explanations on this?

Thanks
Pascal

Comment: Please post the exact error message.

Comment: Well, you wouldn't instantiate a function. You instantiate a class. That line you posted is trying to instantiate a function into an object, which wont work

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function connexObjet() in C:\Apache24\htdocs\tuto_php_1401\articlesManager.php on line 30

Comment: Do you have php mysqli extension installed?

Comment: Why can't I assign a function to a variable?

Comment: @ AngularAddict, yes it works as a procedure, I want to understand the basics of objects

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming these functions are class methods.  Try:

```
$conn = $this->connexObjet();
```

Comment: well done... I should look further into object programming. Thanks

Comment: Oops this line misses something I guessprintf("Connect failed: %s\n");

Comment: anyway, the printf condition is not working if I use printf("Connect failed:\n"); and change the connection parameters to something wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: @bpascal123 now you're in the method, but something's wrong with the constants..  try `$f_conn = new mysqli(self::MYHOST, self::MYUSER, self::MYPASS, self::MYDB);`

Comment: using above returns Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'MYHOST'  in C:\Apache24\htdocs\tuto_php_1401\articlesManager.php on line 14 ... $f_conn = new mysqli...

Comment: Ok, so the constants aren't class constants, but global.  Switch them back to your original, you've got a problem with your connection settings.  Try connecting directly with a mysql client on the command line with the parameters you've set for  MYHOST, MYUSER, etc...

Comment: Actually I have initiated the connection problem so to go through the if condition inside the connexObjet() functions. The if condition shoudl raise the printf connection failed but it's not.